# Why is the Realm of Men not amicable with the Wildings?

Tags: game-of-thrones

So I understand that The Wall was built after The Long Night so as to ensure that The Others remain north of the Realm of Men...

But at what point in Westeros history did the Wildings become so shunned that they were also to be forever incarcerated north of the wall?

Comment: You mean besides refusing to obey laws, bow to Kings and Lords, rape, steal and abduct women?

Comment: ...As do the bandits in the mountain of the moon, and yet they still live south of the wall.

Comment: They live in the mountains, where they can hide, and they are shunned. The wildlings would probably live south of the wall if they could, but then they would have to restrict their freedom.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Your question is a misnomer. The Free Folk (called the Wildings by those South of the Wall) do not consider themselves "incarcerated" North of the Wall of Westeros.**

- They consider themselves free of the laws, rules, and petty conflicts done in the name of Kings and Country.
- They didn't do anything per se to be North of the Wall other than wanting to be free from being forced to submit to rulership.
- The Free Folk consider it a lifestyle choice to live above the Wall and to raid the Southern Kingdoms for food, resources, and anything else they deem necessary. For many tribes it is a ritual of passage into adulthood to raid southern kingdoms.

**From a Wiki of Ice and Fire, re: [Free Folk (Wildings)](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Wildlings)**

> - The Free Folk are a race of people who live beyond the Wall. They are more commonly referred to as "wildlings" everywhere south of the Wall.
> - There are tens, possibly hundreds of thousands of free folk split into hundreds of cultures, tribes, clans, villages and raiding parties, some reasonably cultured, others savage and hostile.
> - The free folk refer to themselves in that way to difference themselves from the "kneelers," the people south of the Wall, subject to lords and kings.
> - The free folk view the "kneelers" as lacking freedom, whereas the people of the Seven Kingdoms to the south view the "wildlings" as lawless and primitive killers, rapists and thieves.